# Could not set permission for new database on postgresql?

Tags: 20.04, postgresql

I'm the beginner in PostgreSQL, today I cannot create new TABLESPACE on my HDD disk. Specifically:

- I'm running the **Ubuntu 20.04** on the **SSD**. Install and using **Postgres 13** normally on this disk.
- I want to create new DATABASE on the other **HDD** disk, due to the data size will be very huge.
- I have run `sudo chown postgres:postgres /destination/folder/on/HDD` as well as `sudo chown 700 /destination/folder/on/HDD` before using postgres to create tablespace.
- Access to postgres terminal by `sudo -u postgres psql` then run `create tablespace table_name location '/destination/folder/on/HDD';`
- It raise the error
  `ERROR:  could not set permissions on directory "/destination/folder/on/HDD": Permission denied`

So how to solve this problem? How can I create new database on HDD disk?
Thanks for your help!